# CakePHP Router not working in PHP class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-routing

I'm using CakePHP 3.x+.

I have created a library class to download youtube videos using `youtube-dl` and return local URL of the file.

**APP/src/Library/AnujTools/YoutubeDownload.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Library\AnujTools;

use Cake\Routing\Router;

class YoutubeDownload
{
    public function download()
    {
        $user_upload_dir = 'files/youtube-video/123/';
        $file_name = '324354554.mp4'

        //
        // download script here
        //

        $url = Router::url('/', true) . $user_upload_dir . $file_name;
        return $url;
    }
}
```

The file is downloaded to location

```
WWW_ROOT . 'files/youtube-video/123/324354554.mp4';
```

**and `return` statement must return**

```
https://example.com/files/youtube-video/123/324354554.mp4
```

**But it returns only**

```
files/youtube-video/123/324354554.mp4
```

Debugging `debug(Router::url('/', true));` gives only `/`

Comment: You can use array path like `[controller => Pages,action=>index]` and please show your `routes.php` file

Comment: I want the base URL, not URL of the index page, only the domain name.

Comment: `$this->Url->build('/', true);` might help

Comment: The `App.fullBaseUrl` config option is probably empty, for whatever reason (`bootstrap.php` should set it if not already defined)...

Comment: setting `App.fullBaseUrl` is not working though. `Router::url('/', true);` works in Controller and model. But, I want to use it in my Library class file.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" isn't an overly helpful depiction of the situation I'm afraid, as that config option is the source where the router gets the base URL from (unless manually set via `Router::fullBaseUrl()`). You'll have to do some more debugging,  and/or provide more context, starting with where exactly and how exactly your class is being used.